# Google PubSub - restarting subscription after exception raised

Tags: python-3.x, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-pubsub

Good day,

I am running some long-running async jobs using PubSub to trigger a function. Occasionally, the task may fail. In such cases, I simply want to log the exception, acknowledge the message, and restart the  subscription to ensure that the subscriber is still pulling new messages after the failure has occurred.

I have placed some simplified code to demonstrate my current set up below:

```
try:
    while True:
        streaming_pull_future = workers.subscriber.subscribe(
            subscription_path, callback=worker_task <- includes logic to ack() the message if it's failed before
        )

        print(f'Listening for messages on {subscription_path}')

        try:
            streaming_pull_future.result()
        except Exception as e: 
            print(streaming_pull_future.cancelled()) #<-- this evaluates to false
            streaming_pull_future.cancel() #<-- this results in RunTimeError: set_result can only be called once.
            print(e)

except KeyboardInterrupt: # seems to be an issue as per Github PubSub issue #17. No keyboard interrupt
    streaming_pull_future.cancel()
```

I keep seeing a `RuntimeError: set_result can only be called once`when I execute the streaming_pull_future.cancel() in the exception handler. I checked whether perhaps the subscriber had already been cancelled but when I logged out the status it evaluated to False. Yet when I then call the cancel() method I get the error. I want to ensure that any threads are cleaned up before making a new subscription in the case where I could have several errors. Does anyone know why this is happening and a way around it?

I am running Python 3.7.4 with PubSub 1.2.0 and grpcio 1.27.1.

---

**Update:**

As per comments, please see a reproducible example. The stack trace raised is included:

```
    Listening for messages on projects/trigger-web-app/subscriptions/load-job-sub
968432700946405
Top-level exception occurred in callback while processing a message
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\..\lib\site-packages\google\cloud\pubsub_v1\subscriber\_protocol\streaming_pull_manager.py", line 
71, in _wrap_callback_errors
    callback(message)
  File "test.py", line 19, in worker_task
    a = 1/0 # cause an exception to be raised
ZeroDivisionError: division by zero
968424309156485
Top-level exception occurred in callback while processing a message
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\...\lib\site-packages\google\cloud\pubsub_v1\subscriber\_protocol\streaming_pull_manager.py", line 
71, in _wrap_callback_errors
    callback(message)
  File "test.py", line 19, in worker_task
    a = 1/0 # cause an exception to be raised
ZeroDivisionError: division by zero
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test.py", line 29, in main
    streaming_pull_future.result()
  File "C:...\lib\site-packages\google\cloud\pubsub_v1\futures.py", line 105, in result
    raise err
  File "C:\...\lib\site-packages\google\cloud\pubsub_v1\subscriber\_protocol\streaming_pull_manager.py", line 
71, in _wrap_callback_errors
    callback(message)
  File "test.py", line 19, in worker_task
    a = 1/0 # cause an exception to be raised
ZeroDivisionError: division by zero

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test.py", line 35, in <module>
    main()
  File "test.py", line 31, in main
    streaming_pull_future.cancel()  
  File "C:\...\lib\site-packages\google\cloud\pubsub_v1\subscriber\futures.py", line 46, in cancel
    return self._manager.close()
  File "C:\...\lib\site-packages\google\cloud\pubsub_v1\subscriber\_protocol\streaming_pull_manager.py", line 
496, in close
    callback(self, reason)
  File "C:\...\lib\site-packages\google\cloud\pubsub_v1\subscriber\futures.py", line 37, in _on_close_callback
    self.set_result(True)
  File "C:\...\lib\site-packages\google\cloud\pubsub_v1\futures.py", line 155, in set_result
    raise RuntimeError("set_result can only be called once.")
RuntimeError: set_result can only be called once.
```

```
import os
from google.cloud import pubsub_v1

subscriber  = pubsub_v1.SubscriberClient()

project_id=os.environ['GOOGLE_CLOUD_PROJECT']
subscription_name=os.environ['GOOGLE_CLOUD_PUBSUB_SUBSCRIPTION_NAME']
subscription_path = f'projects/{project_id}/subscriptions/{subscription_name}'

def worker_task( message ):

    job_id = message.message_id
    print(job_id)
    a = 1/0 # cause an exception to be raised
    message.ack()


def main():
    streaming_pull_future = subscriber.subscribe(
            subscription_path, callback=worker_task
        )

    print(f'Listening for messages on {subscription_path}')

    try:
        streaming_pull_future.result()
    except Exception as e:  
        streaming_pull_future.cancel()  # if exception in callback handler, this will raise a RunTimError
        print(e)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Thank you.

Comment: As per the documentation....cancelled()
Actions in Pub/Sub generally may not be canceled.
This method always returns False https://googleapis.dev/python/pubsub/latest/publisher/api/futures.html

Comment: Thanks @PaddyPopeye but I am talking about subscribers https://googleapis.dev/python/pubsub/latest/subscriber/api/futures.html

Comment: also as a test you could try to add a print(streaming_pull_future.done()) prior to the streaming_pull_future.cancel() invocation... and post the results

Comment: Yea done that already and I do get True on stdout. So I am assuming that an exception does resolve the future. But then the docs themselves seem to be incorrect, or at  least not fully explanatory https://cloud.google.com/pubsub/docs/pull#AsynchronousPull

Comment: As per the documentation result() in a future will block indefinitely if `timeout` is not set, unless an exception is encountered first. For testing what happens if you try below and set a timeout..........                                                                                                                                                                     
"try:
    streaming_pull_future.result(timeout=timeout)
except:  
    streaming_pull_future.cancel()"

Comment: Agreed, however, in my case I want there to be a constant listener on the subscription. So it is not an issue if the thread is blocked. I just need to ensure that if it encounters an exception in the callback (say an api rquest failed) then I can clean up any threads and start the subscription again.  I will try that and get back shortly.

Comment: So I think I have a better idea what may be going on. I think that the docs are set up for the timeout exception, and not for any exceptions arising from the callback function. I used a timeout and see that an exception is raised, but the  streaming_pull_future.done() evaluates to false. This then means you can cancel() the future as it has not resolved. Whereas if an exception is raised in the callback (not from the timeout) the future does resolve and therefore you cannot cancel the future, and therefore another exception gets raised if you try to do so.

Comment: At this point to go any deeper I think we would need a minimal working example of the code .. especially if you are still receiving the " set_result can only be called once" error

Comment: I have added a reproducible example in the question, along with the stack trace.

Comment: You do not appear to be acknowledging your messages, can you please try to ack the messages and re test, take a quick look at the callback() in the tutorial here ..... https://cloud.google.com/pubsub/docs/quickstart-client-libraries

Comment: Acking the message would not solve the issue as the exception is raised before. I do not want to ack the message on exception as I am happy for it to retry if the exception is raised. My actual callback makes several API calls and therefore if any of those raise an exception I would like the message to be re-sent after the deadline and the callback to take place again. Regardless I have included the ack line and the problem persists.

Comment: The correct method is message.ack() not message.acknowledge()..  I think yo u need to review the error handling section of this document https://google-cloud-python.readthedocs.io/en/0.32.0/pubsub/subscriber/index.html

Comment: Apologies, you are correct. The type in my code above was due to typing in via phone. However, the problem persists. The issue does not relate to the acknowledgement of messages, but rather the nature of the futures and how they are handling exceptions

Comment: ok here is all the needed information to implement what you need.. I would suggest reading in order

Comment: Using retries to build reliable serverless systems.. https://cloud.google.com/blog/products/serverless/cloud-functions-pro-tips-using-retries-to-build-reliable-serverless-systems how to build idempotent functions https://cloud.google.com/blog/products/serverless/cloud-functions-pro-tips-building-idempotent-functions Retries and idempotency in action https://cloud.google.com/blog/products/serverless/cloud-functions-pro-tips-retries-and-idempotency-in-action ,.. Retrying Background Functions https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/bestpractices/retries

Comment: I'm not sure those links are all that relevant. I'm having a somewhat similar problem. Looks like there is a way to handle exceptions in futures: https://github.com/googleapis/python-pubsub/blob/master/google/cloud/pubsub_v1/futures.py#L107

Comment: Did you ever figure this out @Snek?